# Display multiple SQL query results as array with RecordSet Object in Autoit

Tags: sql, autoit, adodb, recordset

I am trying to read multiple results after SQL query with ADODB object in Auoit.

```
$sqlCon = ObjCreate ("ADODB.Connection") ; Create SQL connection
$sqlCon.Open("DRIVER={SQL Server};" & $MY_PASS) ; Connect with required credentials
$rs = ObjCreate("ADODB.RecordSet") ; Creating a Record set object
$rs.Open($MY_QUERY, $sqlCon) ; Executing a query

$rs.GetString ;this return all (for example 4) records in one string
```

1. how to read only one specified record? `$rs.RecordNumber(0).GetString`??
2. how to get number of records returned? `$rs.RecordCount` ??
3. how to place records to array one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Now I just found that method GetRosw() will do the job I was looking for

```
$arr = $rs.GetRows()
$records_number = Ubound($arr)
_ArrayDisplay($arr)
```